# Да или нет при ответе на вопрос

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мама спрашивает у дочери в спешке: 
"Ты случайно не забыла кроссовки?"

Я бы ответил автоматически: "Нет, не забыл".

Но девочка ответила: "Да. Не забыла".

Как правильно ответить в данном случае?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ "Да. Не забыла" на вопрос, содержащий отрицание, невозможен.

– Ты не забыла? –  Нет, не забыла.

---

[Об ответе на отрицательный вопрос в русском языке... 
Как ПРАВИЛЬНО отвечать?](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wyf17h1QwDkJ:https://otvet.mail.ru/question/167303199%20&cd=3&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)

По ссылке - ответ мой (с примерами и авторитетным источником).

Comment: Про "да" ничего не нашел в вашем источнике. Там только про "нет".

Comment: Конечно! ))) Речь же об ответе на вопрос, содержащий отрицание. Никогда не будет "да" (потому - что об ём говорить), только "нет".

Answer (score 0):

В устной речи важна **интонация**: девочка могла услышать **главное** в вопросе двояко: 1) "**не забыла?**" - тогда вполне резонный ответ - "да, "**не забыла**", 
**2)** не **"забыла?"** - тогда ответ - "**нет**, не "**забыла**".
Но здесь наречие "случайно" создает интонацию в пользу 2) варианта, поэтому в этом случае - "нет, не забыла"