# "Да, не осталось" или "нет, не осталось"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вот интервью Алексея Кудрина:

— Неужели других ресурсов, чтобы платить старикам хотя бы нынешнюю скромную пенсию, не осталось?
— Скажу прямо: **да, не осталось**.

(["Аргументы и факты"](http://www.aif.ru/money/economy/aleksey_kudrin_mnogie_uprekayut_menya_v_tom_chto_ya_polevel))

А вот ответ @GalinaAvanesova ([Да или нет при ответе на вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431183/%D0%94%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)):  Ответ "Да. Не забыла" на вопрос, содержащий отрицание, невозможен. – Ты не забыла? – **Нет, не забыла**.

Душой я с Галиной, но где доказательства? Есть ли авторитетный источник?

Comment: «Аргументам» надо было бы ДА союзом сделать: «Скажу прямо — да не осталось». Не Кудрин знаки расставлял.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что здесь "работает" такое правило:

В диалогах ***нет*** употребляется в ответных репликах.
Если вопрос не содержит в себе отрицания, то слово *нет* в ответе является отрицающим. Ответ при этом часто повторяет как отрицание соответствующую часть вопроса:
*Разве Ирочка страдала оттого, что жила в давно не крашенной, не очень светлой комнате? Нет, не страдала* (Погод.).

Если первая реплика содержит отрицание, то слово *нет* служит для подтверждения отрицающего (негативного) ответа:

*— Вы не читали эту книгу?

— Нет, не читал.*

*А во владение имениями не вступили? — спросил Бабурин. — Нет, не вступил, — отвечал я* (Тург.).
[**Слово НЕТ как эквивалент предложения. § 2650**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2641-2660.html)

Поэтому, думаю, правильно будет так:
*— Неужели других ресурсов... не осталось?

— Скажу прямо: **нет**, не осталось.*

Comment: Все это доказывает, что "нет, не осталось" — корректно. Для логической полноты нужно еще доказать, что "да, не осталось" — некорректно.

Comment: Строго говоря, "нет, не осталось" - ответ на другой по форме вопрос: "а других ресурсов не осталось?" В данном же вопросе (с "неужели") специфический акцент: "а верно ли утверждение, что других ресурсов не осталось?" - Да [верно; это так], не осталось.

Comment: @М_Г *нужно еще доказать, что "да, не осталось  — некорректно"* - а вот это доказать невозможно потому, что это не так. ))) Нет возможно сти сейчас писать подробно, может позже, но если совсем кратко, то в русском языке "да" и "нет" (в отличие, например, от английского) являются подтверждением/отрицанием семантики высказывания, в том числе и отрицательного по струтуре, а не вормальным следствием наличия  отрицательной частицы в таком предложении. Это вполне позволяет считать ответ типа "Да, не знаю" вполне себе корректным.

Comment: @Мимоходов Буду рад получить дополнительную информацию и ссылки.

Comment: @М_Г, позже тогда. . А источники? Ну какие тут источники могут быть, кроме самого языка?  Грамматика формально не запрещает подобного, а что не запрещено, то разрешено. Вот если вы найдете авторитетный прямой запрет, на подобное (во что я не верю, естественно), это будет аргументом.

Comment: Вот для начала посмотрите, как это это представляют в грамматиках английского. Характерная вещь. Там и "Нет, знаю" и "Да, не знаю"... - всё есть на русском. Вряд ли бы это кочевало из учебника в учебник, будь это грамматической ошибкой.